# Is there a way to make a bar plot from only the non-diagonal elements of a confusion matrix?

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm running a classification task for 3 depth cateogries of earthquakes (shallow, inter, deep) and a 4th category for noise. I'm trying to visualise the varying size of mislabelling in classification by building a barplot from the non-diagonal elements of a confusion matrix.

making the confusion matrix and removing the diagonal elements:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(df_val, pred_labels, labels=inp.labels_list, normalize='true')
cm=cm[~np.eye(cm.shape[0],dtype=bool)].reshape(cm.shape[0],-1) #removes diagonal components
frequency = cm.flatten() #making into row vector
```

building a Dataframe:

```
mislabel_counts={
    'depth categories': ('shallow','shallow','shallow','inter','inter','inter','deep','deep','deep','noise','noise','noise'),
    'mislabelled as:': ('inter','deep','noise','shallow','deep','noise','shallow','inter','noise','shallow','inter','deep'),
    'frequency': tuple(frequency),
    }  
mislabel_counts=pd.DataFrame(mislabel_counts)
```

The DataFrame ends up looking like this:

```
   depth categories    mislabelling  frequency
0           shallow           inter   0.362903
1           shallow            deep   0.209677
2           shallow           noise   0.233871
3             inter         shallow   0.177778
4             inter            deep   0.229630
5             inter           noise   0.296296
6              deep         shallow   0.183486
7              deep           inter   0.348624
8              deep           noise   0.238532
9             noise         shallow   0.166667
10            noise           inter   0.318182
11            noise            deep   0.257576
```

plotting:

```
sns.set_theme(font_scale=2.5)
sns.color_palette('colorblind')
sns.barplot(data=mislabel_counts, x='depth categories', y='frequency', hue='mislabelled as:', width=0.5)
```

The plot ends up looking like this:

[image]

My issue with this being that the plot saves spaces for the diagonal components even though they've been removed. Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to create a `sns.catplot` with `sharex=False`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

mislabel_counts = {
    'depth categories': ('shallow', 'shallow', 'shallow', 'inter', 'inter', 'inter', 'deep', 'deep', 'deep', 'noise', 'noise', 'noise'),
    'mislabelled as:': ('inter', 'deep', 'noise', 'shallow', 'deep', 'noise', 'shallow', 'inter', 'noise', 'shallow', 'inter', 'deep'),
    'frequency': [.362903, .209677, .233871, .177778, .229630, .296296, .183486, .348624, .238532, .166667, .318182, .257576]
}
mislabel_counts = pd.DataFrame(mislabel_counts)

sns.set()
sns.catplot(data=mislabel_counts, kind='bar', x='mislabelled as:', y='frequency', col='depth categories',
            hue='mislabelled as:', dodge=False, sharex=False)

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot to emulate barplot without gaps]

With some fine-tuning, it looks more similar to a regular bar plot:

```py
sns.set_theme(style='whitegrid')
g = sns.catplot(data=mislabel_counts, kind='bar', x='mislabelled as:', y='frequency', col='depth categories',
            hue='mislabelled as:', dodge=False, sharex=False, aspect=0.5, width=1)
for  ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_title())
    ax.set_title('')
    ax.margins(x=0.05)
sns.despine(left=True, top=True, right=True)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
```

[image: make sns.catplot look like sns.barplot]